# Java try catch finally seems pointless

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

This is a quite silly question but i don't understand the combined use of catch and finally. As far as i know the code after a catch block will be executed whether or not an exception will be raised, so why using

```
try
{
    doSomething();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    doSomethingInFinally();
}
```

instead of

```
try
{
    doSomething();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

doSomethingInFinally();
```

? I always see people using the first pattern but i think it is extra code.

Comment: Try throwing an `Error` from `doSomething();` and see what happens with your second code.

Comment: but what if you will get not exception but other throwable class? then you will not catch it and `doSomethingInFinally();` will not be executed. finally is best option to be 100% that something will be executed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are cases where your suggestion doesn't work

- There is no catch statement at all (the method will not continue executing if an exception is thrown).
- The catch block re-throws the exception.
- There is a return statement in the try block.
- The catch statement doesn't handle the super-type exception (like `Throwable` in your case).

Answer (score 2):

The best explanation I can give you is to direct you to the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because you will stop execution halfway your `try {}` statement. In your `finally` you might worry about closing file handles, sockets, etc.

Comment: Yes but you can also do that outside the finally block don't you?

Comment: Yes, but let's say that the data was not availabe for your computation, and thus an error is thrown. You might want to return the function (because computing something from nothing is pointless). But not before you close your file handle for instance. `finally` guarantees that the block is executed, even after errors occur

Answer (score 0):

We almost never catch (or should catch) `Exception`. we will be catching a subclass of `Exception`. In that case if an exception that is not handled by the catch clauses are thrown by `doSomething()`, `doSomethingInFinally()` won't be executed in the 2nd example.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java Documentation :

> This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected
>   exception occurs.

And a followup

> Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice,
>   even when no exceptions are anticipated.

And here is a simple scenario why finally is important:

```
LeakableIO i;
try{
  i = new LeakableIO();
  // do more
}catch(MyException e){
   return null;
}

i.close()
```

We assume that there is an error so the `return` is executed, do you think that `i.close()` will be also called after that return? The answer is NO.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that one form may miss out on the final stuff.

`doSomethingAfter` will **almost always** be called. The only time it will not be called is if `doSomethingWithException` throws an exception.

```
public void test1() {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        doSomethingWithException();
    }

    doSomethingAfter();
}
```

`doSomethingAfter` will **always** be called, whatever happens.

```
public void test2() {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        doSomethingWithException();
    } finally {
        doSomethingAfter();
    }
}
```

Even a `return` does not stop it. Again `doSomethingAfter` will **always** be called.

```
public void test3() {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        doSomethingWithException();
        return;
    } finally {
        doSomethingAfter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int method1()
{
    try
    {
       return 1;
        doSomething();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       return 0;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
       System.out.println("Hello user");
    }
}
```

In this above method Hello user will be always printed. because the code which is exist in finally block which will always executed. 
Basically in JDBC the finally block is used to close the connection.